# platform event not created from flow

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, event, platform-event, create-records

I created a flow that triggeres on every created lead and publishes a platform event "leadCreated".
Whenever I manually add a lead in salesforce lightning UI, the platform event is created as expected.
When (the same user) creates the event through the API, we use zapier, the lead gets created just fine. Only the platform event is not created.
I tried using both process & flow builder.

Is there a specific behaviour in platform events that can cause this ?
What is the difference in creating a Lead through API or Salesforce Lighting UI transaction-wise ?

Comment: does the zapier user have run flows permission?

Comment: hi, no he has not. Its the sys-admin user(don't ask). Somehow I can not assign the "run flows" permission to him. 
But again, how can it be that the event is then fired when I add a Lead in salesforce manually, with the same user ? 
Thanks

Comment: Please use edit to show your Flow.